# CAML to get all checked out docs

Tags: powershell, check-out

I ran the following powershell however, it only list 20 items and in reality I have about 50 items for the site I am running for. I am the farm and site admin. I see 50 files when I go to the library setting manage checked out files http://inside.nv.ed/teams/mkt/_layouts/ManageCheckedOutFiles.aspx?List=%7BBF36234B%2D0303%2D470D%2D887C%2D3A4724FFCB58%7D. Any idea why there is a discrepancy?

## Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://inside.nv.ed/teams/mkt"
foreach ($list in ($spWeb.Lists | ? {$_ -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]})) {
    #Write-Host "Scanning List: $($list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)"
    $CAML = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='int'>0</Value></Geq></Where>"
    #$CAML = "<where><isnull><fieldref lookupid='TRUE' name='CheckoutUser'></fieldref></isnull></where>"
    $query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
    $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'" 
    $query.Query = $CAML
    $listitems = $list.GetItems($query)
    #write-host $listitems.Count
    foreach ($item in $listitems)
    {      
        #write-host $item.url
        $fullURL=$spWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($spWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)")
        write-host $fullURL
    }

}
```

Comment: `if !$item.Url.EndsWith(".aspx")) { continue }` Could it be that you are only looking for specific files?

Comment: I took out the aspx line and remodified the entire code.

Comment: Looks like the mystery is lying when there are required columns in the library and they are not filled. http://www.networkworld.com/article/2346678/microsoft-subnet/sharepoint-mystery--the-case-of-the-missing-documents.html So even with this scenario what tweak I need to make to powershell to get all the items

Comment: Looks like you will want to search for both files that have a checked in version, and files that have never been checked in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either it's a bug or by design by Microsoft. We are in the process of migration and we have received tons of complaints that their files are missing. I have no choice but hit the sql db directly. here is the sql query that worked like I intended. I am NOT liable if your record(s) locks up due to this query. Use at your own risk.

```
1. Go to the database and open an new sql query window (from sql management)
2. Execute following query
SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM [WSS_Content_NOV].[dbo].[AllDocs]
  where SiteId='E2FF98A7-B719-428D-8C30-856F08989691' and 
  CheckoutUserId is not null
3. Export the output to excel or csv for department review
```